# Unable to access modified value of imported variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, scope, global-variables

I am new to python and have some problem understanding the scope here.

I have a python module A with three global variables :

```
XYZ = "val1"
ABC = {"k1" : "v1", "k2" : "v2"}
PQR = 1

class Cls_A() :
    def sm_fn_A(self) :
        global XYZ
        global ABC
        global PQR

        XYZ = "val2"
        ABC["k1"] = "z1"
        ABC["k3"] = "v3"
        PQR += 1
```

And another module B :

```
from A import Cls_A, XYZ, ABC, PQR

class Cls_B():
    def sm_fn_B(self) :
        Cls_A().sm_fn_A()
        print XYZ
        print ABC
        print PQR

Cls_B().sm_fn_B()
```

This gives me the following output :

```
val1
{'k3': 'v3', 'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'z1'}
1
```

Since these are all global variables, why do I not get updated values of all the global variables printed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

Three global variables are defined in module `A`, in this code:

```
XYZ = "val1"
ABC = {"k1" : "v1", "k2" : "v2"}
PQR = 1
```

Then new global variables `XYZ`, `ABC`, `PQR` are defined in module `B`, in this code:

```
from A import Cls_A, XYZ, ABC, PQR
```

This line of code creates new variables, just as if the following was written:

```
import A
XYZ = A.XYZ
ABC = A.ABC
PQR = A.PQR
```

It is important to understand that `A.XYZ` and `B.XYZ` are two variables which point to the same object. They are not the same variable.

Then a new object is assigned to `A.XYZ`:

```
    XYZ = "val2"
```

This modified `A.XYZ`, but did not modify `B.XYZ`. The two used to be two variables which pointed to the same object, but now `A.XYZ` points to a different object.

On the other hand, `A.ABC` is not assiciated with a different object. Instead, the object itself is modified. When the object is modified, both `A.ABC` and `B.ABC` still point to the same object:

```
    ABC["k1"] = "z1"
    ABC["k3"] = "v3"
```

The third case is also not a case of object modification, but rather reassignment:

```
    PQR += 1
```

The value was incremented. That created a new object and than thet new object was assigned to `A.PQR`. `B.PQR` is unchanged. This is equivalent to:

```
    PQR = PQR + 1
```

A thing which may not be obvious is that both strings and integers are *immutable* objects in Python (there is no way to change number to `2` to become `3` - one can only assign a different int object to a variable, not change the existing one). Because of that, there is actually no way to change `A.XYZ` in a way that affects `B.XYZ`.

### The dictionary could behave the same way

The reason why with the dictionary it *"worked"* is that the object was modified. If a new dictioanry was assigned to `A.ABC`, that would not work. E.g.

```
    ABC = {'k3': 'v3', 'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'z1'}
```

Now it would not affect `B.ABC`, because the object in `A.ABC` was not changed. Another object was assigned to `A.ABC` instead.

## Not related to modules

The same behaviour can be seen without any modules:

```
A_XYZ = "val1"
A_ABC = {"k1" : "v1", "k2" : "v2"}
A_PQR = 1

B_XYZ = A_XYZ
B_ABC = A_ABC
B_PQR = A_PQR

A_XYZ = "val2"
A_ABC["k1"] = "z1"
A_ABC["k3"] = "v3"
A_PQR += 1

print B_XYZ
print B_ABC
print B_PQR
```

Prints:

```
val1
{'k3': 'v3', 'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'z1'}
1
```

## Solution

Well, don't keep reference to the temporary object. Use the variable which has the correct value.

For example, in module `B`:

```
import A

class Cls_B():
    def sm_fn_B(self) :
        A.Cls_A().sm_fn_A()
        print A.XYZ
        print A.ABC
        print A.PQR

Cls_B().sm_fn_B()
```

Now there is actually no `B.XYZ` variable, which could be wrong. `A.XYZ` is always used.

Comment: My lack of clarity over the import mechanism confused me maybe. You've explained it perfectly though. Thanks a lot, the answer makes a lot of sense.